# Simple Filter representation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filters, discrete-signals, z-transform

Suppose I have an IIR filter in the $z$-domain in the following form:
$$
H\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{1-0.2z^{-1}-0.1z^{-2}}
$$

How do I represent this in MATLAB?

I am pretty sure if I just listed the coefficients as `H = [1 -0.2 -0.1];`
this would be considered wrong. Can somebody help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB assumes that the transfer function has a form like this:

$$ H(z) = \frac{b_0 + b_1z^{-1} + \ ... \ + b_{M}z^{-M}}{1+a_1z^{-1}+ \ ... \ + a_{N}z^{-N}} $$

So then you can read off the coefficients from your equation as $b_0=1$, $a_0=1$ (always assumed), $a_1 = -0.2$, and $a_2 = -0.1$. In MATLAB world, you define the coefficients as:

```
b = 1;
a = [1; -0.2; -0.1];
```

Further, if you wanted to actually use the filter on some signal, you can call the in-built function:

```
filterOutput = filter(b, a, filterInput);
```

Comment: That `filter` command wouldn't give the correct output. It should be `filter(b,a,x)`.

Comment: But i don't have x in the first place, nor its part of the question

Comment: @MattL thanks I fixed that

Comment: @Raykh I guess I assumed you wanted to use the filter, but maybe you meant something else. When you say "How do I represent this in MATLAB?", what do you mean? Do you want to plot the transfer function, look at the pole-zero diagram, or maybe something else?

Comment: I think I can take it from here. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have to define numerator and denominator polynomials. In your case you have

```
b = 1;
a = [1,-0.2, -0.1];
```

Comment: But what's to it from here? Do you do H = b/a?

Comment: @Raykh: The coefficient vectors `a` and `b` completely represent your filter. That was your question. You have to tell us what else you want to do.

Comment: No worries, thank you very much for your help